# inheriting method not working from parent class

Tags: java, inheritance, static-methods, method-call

I was wondering why my child class isn't inheriting correctly.

if i had...

```
public class ArithmeticOp{

    //some constructor

    public static void printMessage(){
        System.out.println("hello");
    }

}
```

and another class

```
public class AddOp extends ArithmeticOp{

    //some constructor

    ArithmeticOp op = new ArithmeticOp();
    op.printMessage();           //returns error
}
```

my eclipse keeps returning "Syntax error on token "printMessage", Identifier expected after this token"

could someone please help? thanks! are there other ways to call methods from the parent class as well from a child class? thanks a bunch!

Comment: Is your code snippet accurate? I thought you would be doing ArithmeticOp op = new AddOp();  Either way static methods always belong to the Class, not Objects.  So inheritance isn't going to work with statics.  I think you want to drop the static keyword and use OOP.  When calling static methods it's generally good practice to always call on the Class e.g. ArithmeticOp.printMessage(), NOT to call on the instance e.g. op.printMessage();

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because you can't put arbitrary code into the class body:

```
public class AddOp extends ArithmeticOp{

    ArithmeticOp op = new ArithmeticOp(); // this is OK, it's a field declaration
    op.printMessage();                    // this is not OK, it's a statement
}
```

The `op.printMessage();` needs to be inside a method, or inside an initializer block.

That aside, your code feels wrong. Why would you want to instantiate an `ArithmeticOp` *inside* one of its own subclasses?

Comment: Oh 'eck it was more fundamental than I thought.  + 1 for reading the compiler error fully!

Comment: @planetjones: I couldn't see it either, I had to fire up Eclipse to spot it :)

Answer (score 0):

It's because that method is declared as static.  I may be mistaken and I'm sure someone will comment if I am but I think you can do:

```
public class AddOp extends ArithmeticOp{

    //some constructor

    ArithmeticOp op = new ArithmeticOp();
    super.printMessage();           //super should call the static method on the parent class
}
```

Or

```
public class AddOp extends ArithmeticOp{

    //some constructor

    ArithmeticOp op = new ArithmeticOp();
    ArithmeticOp.printMessage();           //Use the base class name
}
```

Comment: thanks for helping though! it just needs to be inside a function also to call that statement